# How can compare two excel files for checking the format in python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have one excel sheet with right format(Certain number of headers and specific names). Here I have another excel sheet and I have to check this excel sheet for right format or not(have to be the same number of header and same header names, no issue if the values below header will changed.). how can solve this issue ? NLP or any other suitable method is there?

Comment: Is there any NLP method to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand why you change the accepted answer when the answer I gave was more precise about what you asked :-)

Comment: @A.Wolf : **df_out = pd.DataFrame([('string1',1),('string2',2), ('string3',3)], columns=['Name', 'Value'])
df_out.to_excel('tmp1.xlsx')
** I can't understand this line ..Can u explain ?\

Comment: It creates an Excel file from the dataframe. It was useful only to have a complete working example.

Comment: with those excels you can see the difference of calling the method on two equals Excel files and on two different Excel files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to compare two Excel you could try something like this (I add also some example Excels):

```
def areHeaderExcelEqual(excel1, excel2) :
equals = True
if len(excel1.columns) != len(excel2.columns):
    return False

for i in range(len(excel1.columns)):
    if excel1.columns[i] != excel2.columns[i] :
        equals = False

return equals
```

And that's an application:

```
 import pandas as pd
#create first example Excel
df_out = pd.DataFrame([('string1',1),('string2',2), ('string3',3)], columns=['Name', 'Value'])
df_out.to_excel('tmp1.xlsx')
#create second example Excel
df_out = pd.DataFrame([('string5',1),('string2',5), ('string2',3)], columns=['Name', 'Value'])
df_out.to_excel('tmp2.xlsx')

# create third example Excel
df_out = pd.DataFrame([('string1',1),('string4',2), ('string3',3)], columns=['MyName', 'MyValue'])
df_out.to_excel('tmp3.xlsx')

excel1 = pd.read_excel('tmp1.xlsx')
excel2 = pd.read_excel('tmp2.xlsx')
excel3 = pd.read_excel('tmp3.xlsx')

print(areHeaderExcelEqual(excel1, excel2))
print(areHeaderExcelEqual(excel1, excel3))
```

**Note**: Excel's files are provided just to see the different outputs.
For example, excel1 looks like this: 
[image]

The idea is the same for the other files. To have more insights, see [How to create dataframes](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python).
Here's you're code:

```
f1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
f2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

print(areHeaderExcelEqual(f1, f2))
```

Comment: Is there any method to train the system by using features of right format and then it can detect the wrong format

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I meant about like machine learning and natural language processing.

Comment: I think that if you need a specific number of columns (which can be a parameter) and column names ML and NLP isn't necessary.

Comment: I think that you have to explain better your problem if you think NLP can help :-) Otherwise I think that this explanation answers to your question :-) You can accept this answer (which can help other people) and ask a new question citing this question to ask explicitely for NLP. Those are two different questions.

Comment: Can u explain **([('string1',1),('string2',2), ('string3',3)], columns=['Name', 'Value'** what is string1, 1 and the column =['Name', 'Value' . please explain with a example

Comment: I edited the answer with the excel output. **columns** is a list with the column names, while [('string1',1),('string2',2), ('string3',3)] is the list of the elements in the dataframe. You can see that each tuple (i.e. elements within brackets) is a line in the Excel file.

Comment: Dataframe is fundamental concept in Python, you have to learn it. If you're not familiar with it, please refer to the link I added to the answer.

Comment: Actually I have two excel files , I just need to compare those files. no need to create excel file like you mentioned

Comment: As I said, it was only to have a complete working example

Comment: You can start from readExcel(); but in this way, you can copy & paste the code without have any Excel file and have a meaningful output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for that comparison.

```
import pandas as pd


f1 = pd.read_excel('sheet1.xlsx')
f2 = pd.read_excel('sheet2.xlsx')

header_threshold = 5 # any number of headers
print(len(f1.columns) == header_threshold)
print(f1.columns) # get the column names as values
```

Comment: Can apply any natural language processing methods here ? like train the system that this is the right format excel sheet.

Comment: The code above didn't check the header names . I have check the header names also